Flam under a fermata
The music is notated for me to play a flam but it’s under a fermata. Do I just play it once or do I keep playing flams while director holds the fermata?

A picture of the notation would be helpful.

99% sure you’re just going to play one flam but depending on the specific notation there might be other things you would do. No answer to this will be complete without a recommendation to ask the director/conductor what they want you to do.

As stated above, an image will certainly help us help you much more: take a screenshot or a photo of the score, then [edit] your post with it. Most importantly, the concept of "a flam under a fermata" is ambiguous, as "flam" may refer to both the [ornament](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornament_(music) alone or the composition of the actual note and its ornament: what's actually shown under the fermata? In any case, you almost certainly will not keep "playing flams" during the fermata: it's either a "single flam" that has to be played in the downbeat of that, or considered for what follows.

That's an example of bad writing. There's no telling what the composer or arranger were thinking, if indeed they were thinking at all.
In a situation like this I would play the flam once. It's not uncommon for the percussion to just play the accent at the beginning of a fermata. If the director wants anything else they will tell you.
Alternatively you could just ask the director what they want you to play.
